# RecyclerView Pinning Items / Putting updated item to the top

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view for my note application. I want to add a pinning attribute that pins the selected notes to the top. And similarly i want to put updated notes to the top (But still under the pinning notes). Is there a way to do this?